# I am trying to execute the below line into MySQL and keep getting a 1136 error

Tags: mysql

I am trying to execute the below line into MySQL and keep getting an error

```
INSERT INTO Orders VALUES ("C1000",'2018-04-15', '2018-04-18', 33.98)
```

Error:

> Error 1136 column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Table DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE Orders (
    CustomerID VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    OrderDate DATE NOT NULL,
    ShipDate DATE NOT NULL,
    TotalOrderAmount DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (CustomerID, ShipDate),
    FOREIGN KEY (CustomerID) REFERENCES Customers(CustomerID)
)
```

Can somebody please assist with correcting this error? I have been working on this for a few days and I can't get it.

Comment: I [can't reproduce this error](http://rextester.com/JWZ45565).  Please give us a reproducible problem to look at.

Comment: I also tried the below line and still got the same error                   
                    INSERT INTO Orders (CustomerID, OrderDate, ShipDate, TotalOrderAmount) VALUES ('C1000', '2018-04-15', '2018-04-18', 33.98)

Comment: The semicolon doesn't see to make a difference. I was able to update other tables in the model in the same format, so I'm not sure what is happening with this specific table

Comment: Running perfectly on my localhost (MySQL 5.5).

Answer (score 0):

Where will they get inserted?

You are missing the column names of the table `Orders`.

Comment: You don't need to specify the column names, though it is certainly best practice.  I can't reproduce this problem ([see here](http://rextester.com/JWZ45565)).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Is he getting the error because the is missing `;`?

Comment: Well, I think then the insert would not run at all.  If it does run without the semicolon, then this can't be the reason.

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql> SHOW TRIGGERS;
```

You have a `BEFORE INSERT` or `AFTER INSERT` trigger on the Orders table that is inserting a row into a *different* table whenever you insert into Orders.  The query inside the trigger is incorrect and throwing this error indirectly.